# polkit inactive session action/rules never come into effect

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, xrdp, policykit

I have different issues with polkit not working at all for inactive sessions. Because I think they share the same issue i will post one example first.

I have a fresh ubuntu-server 14.04 with lubuntu-desktop and xrdp package installed. When I login with xrdp I should have the normal restrictions as polkit was defined. First I thought I just don't have enough permission for certain actions. So I changed some configurations to my needs. Here's one example: Doubleclicking a .deb-package I want to install, software-center opens and i click install there:

[image: polkit error message]

> org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.121'}): org.debian.apt.install-file

(Something like: You're not allowed to do this action. You don't own the right permissions.)

Before that I've configured polkit to allow this for my inactive session (but for my understanding auth_admin would be enough though). An `pkaction --verbose` extract:

```
org.debian.apt.install-file:
  description:       Install package file
  message:           To install this package, you need to authenticate.
  vendor:            Apt Daemon
  vendor_url:        http://launchpad.net/aptdaemon/
  icon:              package-x-generic
  implicit any:      auth_admin
  implicit inactive: auth_admin_keep
  implicit active:   auth_admin_keep
```

Anyway I am thinking polkit (agent?) does not run at all, because I get following error right after login with xrdp:

[image: polkit error message logged through xrdp]

> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject

I assume he doesnt find me as user? How can I check if policykit agent is running in my xrdp-session? Can I start it manually? Is this maybe a bug?

Edit: Yes, this user is in the admin group, this user was created during installation of ubuntu. It also has sudo rights.

Comment: Sorry for not having enough reputation to directly include the images into the right places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It doesn't seem to get the user name from the user process, check your environment variables. xrdp may differ from the regular session:

  ```
  env | grep -i "user\|logname"
  ```
- To check if polkit agent is running, use terminal and run this:

  ```
  ~$ ps aux | grep polkit
  root       855  0.0  0.9 281224  7192 ?        Sl   06:34   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
  user      2060  0.0  1.5 331764 11604 ?        Sl   06:37   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
  user      2419  0.0  0.1  15944   952 pts/12   S+   06:38   0:00 grep --color=auto polkit
  ```

  You should find two process `polkitd` running by root and `polkit-*-authentication-agent-1` by same user of the session.
- Yes, you can tart them manually, I have Ubuntu desktop so it may differ. Get where it is:

  ```
  ~$ ls /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-*
  /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop

  ~$ grep -i exec= /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
  Exec=/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
  ```

  Run it:

  ```
  /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
  ```

Comment: running that command will not work since there's an instance already running, may as well do a reboot